# Finding all roots of $x^4-10x^2+1$ without computational approximation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

How can I find, by hand, all four roots of $f(x)=x^4-10x^2+1$?

I can see that it has no linear rational roots, by the root test, and I can't see anyway to factorize it into two quadratic expressions. I would guess that it is irreducible in $\Bbb Q[x]$, so I just want to see what four roots it has in $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ without using computational methods.

Side note: (I know that it splits over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$, so I wanted to see how hard it is to find all four roots, and drew a blank. If I showed all four roots of $f(x)$, which is the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$, were in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ I imagine I would have shown $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint:

Replace $x^2$ with some variable $y$. You now have a quadratic equation that you can solve using the quadratic formula.

Comment: Wow, that seems so obvious after you say it! :D

Comment: Apparently answers are not accepted from this account, so you can add this: By the hint given by Jed:

$$\text{Let } x^2=y, \implies x^4-10x^2+1= y^2-10y+1$$

Using the quadratic formula:
$$\frac{10\pm \sqrt{100-4}}{2}=5\pm \frac{\sqrt{96}}{2}=5\pm 2\sqrt2\sqrt3$$

Then since $x=\pm\sqrt y$ we obtain the four roots:

$$x=(5+2\sqrt2\sqrt3,5-2\sqrt2\sqrt3,-5+2\sqrt2\sqrt3,-5-2\sqrt2\sqrt3)$$

Comment: @Purple diamond .You have $x^2=y=5\pm 2 \sqrt 6$ but the values you have for $\pm \sqrt y$ are incorrect.

Comment: @user254665 Oh yes, I forgot to apply the $\sqrt{\,}$ over each of them, and I applied the $\pm$ therefore 'inside' the square root.

Should have been $\pm \sqrt{5-2\sqrt{6}}$ and so on.

Answer (score 3):

$x^4-10x^2+1=0\iff (x^2-5)^2=24\iff x^2=5\pm2\sqrt 6\iff $ $x\in \{\sqrt 3-\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3+\sqrt 2,-\sqrt 3-\sqrt 2,-\sqrt 3-\sqrt 2\}$.